# Triggering Lookaside lists

Tags: windows, visual-c++, memory-management, heap-memory, internals

I am trying to make my application to use lookaside lists for memory management. I know the following details from various papers on this subject.

1. Lookaside lists are located at offset +0x688 from the heap base
2. Each member is 48 bytes long.
3. lookasidelist[0],lookasidelist[1] not used.
4. lookasidelist[n] block is of size n*8 and used to store (n-1)*8 byte blocks (remaining 8 bytes is used for header) and offset 0 points to a linked list containing free chunks of size (n-1)*8 terminating with null.
5. Lookaside lists are enabled by default in XP SP3 and disabled in Vista/Win 7 systems(Low fragmentation heap is used in Vista/Win 7)

The problem that I am facing is that my application seems to not use Lookaside lists. No allocation seems to originate from lookaside lists and all the freed blocks are moved to freelist. Is there a particular compiler flag or a condition needs to be satisfied in order for the applications to use lookaside lists?
Application is compiled in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 express edition and is tested under Windows XP SP3. I am using immunity debugger for verifying if lookaside lists are being used. If there is a better way do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the process through debugger, attaching to the process at runtime revealed that the application decides to use lookaside lists when it is not being debugged. [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/29/what-a-heap-of-part-two.aspx) is the only place I have seen it documented.

> The heap manager creates look-aside lists automatically when a heap is
>   created, as long as no debugging options are enabled and the heap is
>   expandable.